# WITH SQL statement instead subqueries

Tags: sql, subquery, common-table-expression

I was trying to create a query with "WITH" statement instead of 2 subqueries, without success. Any suggestions?

```
WITH "temp" AS
(
    SELECT 
        productID,
        ProductPrice,
        (CASE 
            WHEN ProductPrice BETWEEN 1 AND 100 THEN '1-100'
            WHEN ProductPrice BETWEEN 101 AND 200 THEN '101-200'
            WHEN ProductPrice BETWEEN 201 AND 300 THEN '201-300'  
            ELSE NULL
         END) product_group
    FROM 
        products 
)
SELECT *
FROM
    (SELECT 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY product_group ORDER BY productprice) AS rn
     FROM 
         temp)
WHERE 
    rn IN (1,2)
```

Comment: What happens when you run this?  Have you tried writing a very simple 'WITH' query to make sure you understand the syntax? What DBMS are you using?

Comment: "without success" Why don't you tell us you get an error, and what the error is? Help people help you! Anyway, you should put your `ROW_NUMBER` in the CTE.

Comment: WITH "temp"? Could you please remove double quotes. And the second SELECT *
FROM
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by product_group order by productprice) as rn
FROM temp) looks strange. Where are allother fields from temp CTE

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: What is the error you get?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
WITH temp as (
SELECT productID,
       ProductPrice,
      (case when ProductPrice between 1 and 100 then '1-100'
            when ProductPrice between 101 and 200 then  '101-200'
            when ProductPrice between 201 and 300 then  '201-300' 
       end) product_group
FROM products )
SELECT * FROM ( SELECT t.*, 
                       ROW_NUMBER() 
                        over (partition by product_group order by productprice) as rn
                  FROM temp t) t
WHERE rn in (1,2)
```

I have just removed the `"` and added `t.*` . everything else looks fine.

Comment: There's still the problem that the subquery in the final `FROM` clause isn't given an alias, which is probably the error that the OP fails to give us.

Comment: Yes, I have added it